# Why my db connection couldn't be accessed from handler?

Tags: database, go

I have code like this:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

// Default constant for configuration
const DefaultHTTPAddr = ":8080"
const DefaultDSN = "root:root@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/librarian"

// Parameters
var (
    httpAddr string
    dsn      string
    db       *sql.DB
)

// init initializes this package.
func init() {
    flag.StringVar(&httpAddr, "addr", DefaultHTTPAddr, "Set the HTTP bind address")
    flag.StringVar(&dsn, "dsn", DefaultDSN, "Set the Data Source Name")
    flag.Usage = func() {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Usage: %s [options]\n", os.Args[0])
        flag.PrintDefaults()
    }

}

type Book struct {
    id     int
    title  string
    author string
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    var err error
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", DefaultDSN)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if err = db.Ping(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // handler
    http.HandleFunc("/", homepage)
    http.HandleFunc("/books", booksIndex)

    log.Println("httpd started successfully")
    http.ListenAndServe(httpAddr, nil)
}

func booksIndex(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method != "GET" {
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(405), 405)
        return
    }

    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM books")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    books := make([]*Book, 0)
    for rows.Next() {
        bk := new(Book)
        err = rows.Scan(&bk.id, &bk.title, &bk.author)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        books = append(books, bk)
    }
    if err = rows.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for _, bk := range books {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%v, %v, %v\n", bk.id, bk.title, bk.author)
    }
}

func homepage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Welcome!")
}
```

Everytime I try to access `/books` it always panic.

```
$ curl localhost:8080/books
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Like this one:

```
2016/05/31 11:56:38 http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:51711: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 6 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc820074100)
        /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1389 +0xc1
panic(0x357b40, 0xc82000a150)
        /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:443 +0x4e9
database/sql.(*DB).conn(0x0, 0xc820010b01, 0xc8200de000, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/database/sql/sql.go:778 +0xac9
database/sql.(*DB).query(0x0, 0x4022c0, 0x13, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x3c4601, 0x6, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/database/sql/sql.go:1073 +0x46
database/sql.(*DB).Query(0x0, 0x4022c0, 0x13, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc820016280, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/database/sql/sql.go:1061 +0xa3
main.booksIndex(0x6979c0, 0xc82006da00, 0xc8200e2000)
        /Users/rahmatawaludin/gocode/src/github.com/rahmatawaludin/librarian/main.go:68 +0xd9
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x4666f8, 0x6979c0, 0xc82006da00, 0xc8200e2000)
        /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1618 +0x3a
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0xc820010ba0, 0x6979c0, 0xc82006da00, 0xc8200e2000)
        /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1910 +0x17d
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc820074080, 0x6979c0, 0xc82006da00, 0xc8200e2000)
        /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:2081 +0x19e
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc820074100)
        /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1472 +0xf2e
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
        /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:2137 +0x44e
```

I thought I could access `db` from `booksIndex` as I set in to be global variable. When I move the db initialization to `booksIndex` the errors doesn't show up.

What parts is wrong in my code?

Also, I'm new in Golang. If you have any suggestion on how to organize my code, please tell me. Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your db variable in function is shadowing global variable.
When you do this:

```
db,err:=
```

It assigns it to a new local variable db.
This is because it's not from same block. According to the standard:

> Unlike regular variable declarations, a short variable declaration may redeclare variables provided they were originally declared earlier
>   in the same block (or the parameter lists if the block is the function
>   body) with the same type, and at least one of the non-blank variables
>   is new. As a consequence, redeclaration can only appear in a
>   multi-variable short declaration. Redeclaration does not introduce a
>   new variable; it just assigns a new value to the original.

So global variable remains nil pointer. And when it is access, you get nil pointer dereference

Change it to d and then assign it later to db. Or which is more correct(as given in comment by rahmat):=

```
d , err =
```

I would recommend you to have separate files for handler, models etc. And look into https://github.com/mattermost/platform to how to organise the code.

Comment: Ahh.. thanks! Changed it to `db, err = sql.Open("mysql", DefaultDSN)` also make it works.. :)

Comment: Yes. I didn't notice that you have declare error also.

Comment: I added your comment as answer as people reads answer  mostly. Upvote if it helps.