# Error while sending data to the database

Tags: go

I'm trying to transfer data to write them to the database.
But I have the error "panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference"
In this function, I wait for the data from the client

```
func handlePacket(conn net.Conn) {
    rw := bufio.NewReadWriter(bufio.NewReader(conn), bufio.NewWriter(conn))
    defer conn.Close()

    packet := model.RegistrationMessage{}
    client := JsonDecoderMessage(rw).Decode(&packet)
    if client != nil {
        puts("Error from Decode.Please NO :(")
    }

    if packet.MessageType == model.AUTH_MESSAGE {
        puts("Auth")
    } else if packet.MessageType == model.REGS_MESSAGE {
        puts("Regs")
        Registration(packet.Login, packet.Password)
        puts("good")
    }
}
```

And here I establish connection with a DB and I try to send the data in a DB

```
var db *sql.DB

func InitDataBase() {
    psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s "+
        "password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable",
        host, port, user, password, dbname)
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Successfully connected!")
}
func Registration(email, password string) {
    sqlStatement := `INSERT INTO account0( email,password)
        VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING id`
    id := 0
    err := db.QueryRow(sqlStatement, email, password).Scan(&id)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Put defer db.Close() in your main function.

Answer (score 7):

`defer db.Close()` will be executed when `InitDataBase()` returns, so when you use `db` in `Registration`, it causes an error.

You should call `db.Close()` just before your program exits, or after you are finished working with the database, whichever comes first.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. I found the answer .You need to change  `db, err: = sql.Open ("postgres", psqlInfo)` to `db, err= sql.Open ("postgres", psqlInfo)`.
The answer found in this link [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37537156/why-my-db-connection-couldnt-be-accessed-from-handler)